# Not able to receive body message in CURL_RTSPREQ_ANNOUNCE

Tags: c++, c, curl, rtsp, sdp

I'm trying to make a rtsp client using curl and in ANNOUNCE response I'm not able to get body with the SPD.

I'm doing this setup.

```
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, fullURL);
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_RTSP_STREAM_URI, fullURL);
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_RTSP_REQUEST, CURL_RTSPREQ_ANNOUNCE);
curl_easy_setopt(ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,sdp);
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &body);
curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_cb);
```

I have a breakpoint in the write_cb function and it does not stop. If I add this option: curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L); the function stops, but only get the header information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that is the answer.

RTSP has no body in the answer of ANNOUNCE, but in my case with EUROCAE,  have body in ANNOUNCE answer.

For manage this situation I have modified curl library, in lib/rtsp.c and define ANNOUNCE as message with body. After that my problem was solved.

Thanks.